# On the definition of covariance matrix

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix, definition

I am having a misunderstanding with the definition of the covariance matrix  from the wikipedia page on the covariance matrix.
It says the covariance matrix $\sum$ is equivalent to

[image]

where

[image]

It seems like this would yield a number rather than a matrix because the above is the expected value of a dot product.

Where am I going wrong? Clearly I am misunderstanding something very basic.

Comment: Also just for your own information, $E[(X-E[X])(X-E[X])]$ is the covariance of $X$ with itself, equivalent to the variance of $X$. i.e. $Cov(X,X) = E[(X-E[X])(X-E[X])] = Var(X)$. Note that the covariance of $X$ with $Y$ would be $E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])]$. Not related, just thought I would make note unless you weren't aware.

Comment: i think because X is a random variable this is the true definition. check out the page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix

Comment: Oh, it is. I was just giving a little supplementary information that you might find interesting :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product is an outer product between a vector of dimension (n x 1) and its transposed version having dimension (1 x n) thus yielding a matrix of dimension (n x n).